# How to implement a directory-based custom project type

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, vsx

I'd need to implement a custom project type that does not rely on a project file at all to persist its data, but, rather, is "bound" to a directory pretty much in the same way as the standard "Website" project works.

I've noticed that the "Website" project persists the path to the directory, as well as the website URL, in the .sln file. Is it possible for a custom project type to do the same, and, if so - how?

Now, since there won't be a project file as such, it looks like I won't be able to use the standard approach to crafting project templates. Moreover, I am required to launch external code to generate the default project contents. I was thinking about implementing a custom wizard, but I am not at all sure if it is possible to craft a template that would just invoke a wizard to create the project and would not include any file-based contents?

Finally, how do I provide an ability to open projects based on a directory and not a file?

Answer (score 0):

I think Python Tools for Visual Studio uses this approach (at least it used to be). It's open source so just take a look how it's done - http://pytools.codeplex.com/